With unbuntu 22.04 and 24.04 cannot access ports defined in the Security Groups
I have been using, on AWS, ubuntu 20.04 version. In the Network settings, I created Security Groups to enable access to ports:
    22 (Type: ssh, Protocol: TCP, Source Type: AnyWhere)
    4200 (Type: Custom TCP, Protocol: TCP, Source Type: My IP)
    8080 (Type: Custom TCP, Protocol: TCP, Source Type: My IP)

then I installed Hortonworks, and from the browser I can access port 22 (SSH), port 8080 (Ambari); and port 4200 (Hortonworks/HDP) filesystem)
Now with unbuntu 22.04 and 24.04, I do the same steps above, I can access port 22 (SSH), BUT when I go to the browser, I cannot access port 8080 (Ambari); and I cannot access port 4200 (HDP filesystem); I get error on the browser:   502 Bad Gateway -- nginx/1.15.0
What could be the change between ubuntu 20.04 vs ubuntu 22.04 which disallow access to these ports?
I appreciate any insight and help.
